# What's the meaning of "complete redacted memory bypass"?

Tags: star-wars, the-rise-of-skywalker

C-3PO speaks to Poe:

> Poe: The inscription that was on the dagger is in your memory?
>
> C-3P0: Master Poe. But the translation from a forbidden language cannot be
> retrieved. That is short of a **complete redacted memory bypass**.Yes,

What's the meaning of "complete redacted memory bypass"?

Comment: A memory bypass that will wipe his memory (completely)

Comment: The novelisation calls it a "complete redact**ive** memory bypass"

Comment: We witness the procedure happen, I’m not really sure what you’re asking if it is shown.

Comment: It's technobable to imply they are going to hack C-3P0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's mostly techno-babble as the comments have said. But the words do have meaning.

Redact in this case means

> censor or obscure (part of a text) for legal or security purposes.

And bypass is a verb here meaning

> go past or around.

So to take the phrase at face value means that they are going to completely go around the censored portion of 3PO's memory to get to the information they need.